# Capturing Contact pick callback to other than onActivityResult or to other non-Activity controller

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I am writing a controller which takes the activity handle, processes data and just invokes activity back. So this controller will invoke contact picker through applying intent on activity.

But I knew that callback onActivityresult goes to activity with which, contact picker is invoked. I feel that separating callback from activity provides more modularity which is important for me.

So wondering if there is a way in capturing callBack(onActivityResult) to class controller that I wish. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't see how it provides more modularity. You're basically trying to replace the default automatic system of handling the result with a manual one with no real benefit(but with more potential problems).

Comment: It brings actually. I have made a library for iPhone app which will handle UI and data processing when invoked from screen. Based upon state of action controller of that library calls back to screen. It basically separates implementation of data handling from activity to a separate class(s).

Comment: Ex: I pick a contact, I have to collect data of it, save reference in db, send as a post on chat room. Its a lot of code right?